# Change font on all controls on Microsoft Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba, fonts, report

I have a very complex Microsoft Access report. This report is run for multiple customers. I would like to change the font on a subset** of controls on the report (there are tons) for a particular customer, but not for others. Since the font is set at the control level, is it possible to change it programatically?

**The criteria that selects the subset would be based on the current font. For example, I would want to change the font on all controls which currently use Arial.

Comment: Do you want to change the font a run-time or in design view? Either is simple enough.

Comment: @Remou, I want to change it at runtime, based on a customer id, for a subset of controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
If Me.OpenArgs = "1" Then
    ChangeFont Me
End If
End Sub


Sub ChangeFont(rpt As Report)
Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In rpt.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then
            ChangeFont ctl.Report
        ElseIf ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            If ctl.FontName = "Calibri" Then

                 ctl.FontName = "Times"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewDesign, , , acHidden
For Each ctl In Reports.Item("AmbulanceServices")
  If ctl.FontName = "Arial" Then
    ctl.FontName = "Tahoma"
    ctl.FontSize = 10
  End If
Next
DoCmd.Save acReport, "MyReport"
```

Comment: That will change the fonts for keeps, yesno?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can probably avoid this by opening the report in view mode and running similar code - without saving. You can also minimize the report so users will not see the changes as they occur.

Comment: You also need to watch out for controls such as labels that you may not wish to change and subforms that do not have fonts.